# Write-Only Memory

Tags: memory, language-agnostic

I know there exists read-only values in many languages (`final` in Java `const` in C++ etc.) but does such a thing as "Write-Only" values exist? I've heard a variation of this in jokes, such as write-only code, but I'm wondering if this is actually a legitimate concept in computer science. To be honest, I can't see how it would be helpful in any situation, but I'm just wondering.

Comment: What you cam only write, somebody else might be able to read.

Comment: There are no write-only or read-only values, it doesn't make sense to say that zero is read-only for example. Storage locations can have such properties.

Comment: Images in OpenCL can be either read-only or write-only, with read-write being an optional extension (hardly supported by any vendors).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In unix shell scripting there is a concept of write only memory. But it's not part of any shell or scripting language, it's a device: `/dev/null`.

The write-only device `/dev/null` is used to discard output you don't want. Generally by allowing the caller to redirect stdout and/or stderr to it.

There are other write-only memory on a computer. One example is your sound card which on some (older) unix machines are mapped to `/dev/audio` or `/dev/dsp`. Writing values to it makes your speaker produce sound but reading from it gets you nothing.

At the lower level of the device drivers themselves, these hardware devices are often connected to a specific memory or I/O address (some CPU architectures don't have separate memory and I/O address - just a single address space shared by RAM and all other hardware). So in a real sense these memory locations are really write-only.

Comment: I've also just realized that file streams can be read-only, write-only or read-write. `stdout` for example is usually write-only.

Answer (score 2):

There were certainly some FPUs for PCs that used a somewhat weird setup, by existing as memory-mapped devices. To perform some operations, you would simply write the value you wanted to operate on, to a memory address indicating what operation you wanted performed, the value would then (eventually) be available at another address.

I don't know if you would define this, strictly, as "write-only memory", it is rather memory where (part of) the address is used as an opcode.